# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (Параметр должен быть массивом или объектом, который реализует счет в)

Tags: php

Дорогие коллеги объясните пожалуйста мне одну вещь, в метод `count()` передаю объект (мне это так казалось, а как оказалось там был Json ответ гугл аналитики). Значит мне выпало предупреждение

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

Сначала я ему как он и хотел сунул массив но он мне не выдал результата и соответственно предупреждения, далее я ему скормил уже объект, а теперь показался и результат и предупреждение тоже.

Мне эти предупреждения с роду не нравились (не покажешь же ты их конечному пользователю), ну я ему и подсунул собаку. вот собственно и пример кода

```
if (@count((object)$results->getRows()) > 0) {
```

Так вот хотелось бы услыхать возможно ли такое делать в принципе? А если нет то по каким причинам. Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

> Так вот хотелось бы услыхать возможно ли такое делать в принципе?

Ну с массивом все и так ясно

```
<?php
$a[0] = 1;
$a[1] = 3;
$a[2] = 5;
var_dump(count($a));
```

А вот с объектами тут другая история, но тоже всё легко. Нужно всего-то имплементировать интерфейс `Countable`,  у которого есть одноименный метод `count`.

Вот пример с офф. сайта:

```
class CountMe implements Countable 
{ 

    protected $_myCount = 3; 

    public function count() 
    { 
        return $this->_myCount; 
    } 

} 

$countable = new CountMe(); 
echo count($countable); //result is "3" as expected
```

---

Так как в вашем примере ни того ни другого, вы получаетет ошибку.

- [Countable](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.countable.php)
- [count](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php)

Answer (score 2):

Ну как всегда, выскажу свое мнение:

Итак, нашего бульдога ставят на охрану только в случаях неопределенности, таких случаев очень мало, например раньше часто использовали при удалении файлов, инклудов. Сейчас реже и реже. Смысл в том что ваш код по дефолту должен работать без каких либо ошибок, если вам нужно засунуть в `count` объект, то можно использовать типа:

`count(get_object_vars($OBJECT))`

Делать такое можно, НО вы должны понимать, что вызывая собаку вы замедляете работу скрипта. На глазок самым долгим будет `count` с генерацией ошибки (вообще любая генерация ошибки очень ресурсоемкая и долгая, поэтому и избегают), потом будет идти `@count` и самый быстрый вариант `count` без ошибки.

Теперь осталось определить, к чему ближе `@` к первому варианту(самому долгому) или к последнему (самому быстрому). Скорей к первому, почему, потому-что собака подавляет не все виды ошибок, а лишь некоторые, например `ParseError` будет и с собакой приводить к критической ошибке. В двух словах схема такова: возникает ошибка, вызывается генератор ошибок, он определяет ошибку (это уже ресурсоемкий процесс), дальше проверяет может ли собака его подавить, если да то заканчиваем дело, если нет - выбиваем критулю.

Я под юбку интерпретатору не заглядывал, но вроде как так. Сама концепция - одинаковая, собаки - плохо, кошки лучше, особено британские либо шотландские :)

Comment: Спасибо. Я не не из плохих побуждений. Для улучшения своих знаний.Так сказать повышение квалификации.

Answer (score 1):

> if (@count((object)$results->getRows()) > 0)
>
> Так вот хотелось бы услыхать возможно ли такое делать в принципе? А если нет то по каким причинам. Благодарю за ответы.

**Варианты :**

```
if (count((array)$results->getRows()))
```

1. Убеждаемся что `$results->getRows()` точно массив через приведение
   типов (`(array)$results->getRows()`). Поскольку там по сути может
   быть любой тип.
2. Ваш класс от которого был создан экземпляр объекта `$results` имплементировать от интерфейса [**Countable**](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.countable.php) и реализовать собственный метод `count`.Классы, реализующие интерфейс `Countable`, могут быть использованы с функцией `count()`.

Если сложен 2 вариант то выбирайте 1.Хотя на всякий случай знайте что агрегирование объектов в массив и наоборот всегда ресурсозатратная работа.

Собака (**@**) это медленный оператор,так не надо делать, поскольку вы вредите себе дважды.Это тоже самое что если бы вы выключили вывод ошибок (`error_reporting(0)`), произвели бы что либо и обратно его включили бы (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`).

И помните тоже что нету смысла на всякий проверять на больше нуля в [логических конструкциях (if)](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php), так как любое выражение в PHP приводятся к [**булеву типу**](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php) (`TRUE` или `False`). `0 = FALSE`, а  `> 0`  это TRUE.

Comment: Тут дело в том что я использую библиотеку классов Google Analytics и этот код мне выдавал ошибку когда я хотел вывести больше одного значения полученного в ответ на запрос. Тоесть хотел вывести все значения из массива а ему только один хочется. Вот я и решил такое дело топорным методом. Понимаю, что это плохо, а почему не знаю. Спасибо за ответ плюсанул.